# Rails active record maintain order from array after find

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm passing find an array of ids, and i'd like to keep the objects in the same order i pass. I assume the order they get set is whatever the primary order set to in the model.

**order of array**

```
just items = [488800, 489404, 485616, 380112, 501101, 485606, 485612, 485619, 480304, 493609, 496200, 496203, 503000, 499111, 488802, 488825, 501700]
```

**Order of what active record gives**

```
@item_recomendations = CatalogItem.find(just_items)
@item_recomendations.map {|x| x.id }
 => [380112, 480304, 485606, 485612, 485616, 485619, 488800, 488802, 488825, 489404, 493609, 496200, 496203, 499111, 501101, 501700, 503000]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@item_recomendations = CatalogItem.find(just_items).sort_by{|x| just_items.index x.catalog_item_id }
```

Answer (score 0):

If performance isn't an issue (and you should try this and benchmark first to prove it is), just iterate over the array yourself:

```
items.collect { |id| CatalogItem.find(id) }
```